# AngularJS error: fnPtr is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, spring, angularjs

I'm trying to write a sample AngularJS, and SpringMVC project. The spring methods works fine, but I have a problem with declaraton of function in my site controller. My app should return a word from text input, but when I click the button, I've got this error:

```
[13:23:58.900] "Error: fnPtr is not a function
parser/_functionCall/<@http://localhost:8080/example/resources/js/Angular/angular.js:6542
ngEventDirectives[directiveName]</</</<@http://localhost:8080/example/resources/js/Angular/angular.js:13256
Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8080/example/resources/js/Angular/angular.js:8218
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/example/resources/js/Angular/angular.js:8298
ngEventDirectives[directiveName]</</<@http://localhost:8080/example/resources/js/Angular/angular.js:13255
createEventHandler/eventHandler/<@http://localhost:8080/example/resources/js/Angular/angular.js:2095
forEach@http://localhost:8080/example/resources/js/Angular/angular.js:130
createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://localhost:8080/example/resources/js/Angular/angular.js:2094
"
```

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Apken">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="resources/js/Angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/controler.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="theNamer">

<div class="input-append">
    <input style="width:358px;" class="span2" type="text" ng-model="myName" required min="1" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!myName" ng-click="send()">Click!</button>
</div>
<ul>
<li  ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

And controler.js:

```
function theNamer ($scope,$http){
    $scope.myName='aa';

    $scope.fetchList=new function()
    {
        $http.get('ca/list.json').success(function(thList){
            $scope.names = thList;
        });
    }

        $scope.send=new function()
        {

            $http.post('ca/set/3').success(function(){

            $scope.fetchList;

            });

        }
        $scope.fetchList;


}

var Apken = angular.module('Apken',[]);
Apken.controller('theNamer', theNamer);
```

I've noticed, that must be a some kind of problem with function declaration in the ng-click value. On site startup controler.js works fine, but it crashes, when I click the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tested your code. Using AngularJS 1.0.7, the error disappears when you replace

```
$scope.send = new function() {
```

with

```
$scope.send = function () {
```

and same applies to `fetchList`.

I guess you mixed the two syntaxes `function(*args*) { *body* }` and `new Function(*args*, *body*)`. Check on MDN: [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

You have also to change your code in order to get your `fetchList` properly called:

```
function theNamer($scope, $http) {

        $scope.myName = 'aa';

        $scope.fetchList = function() {

            $http.get('ca/list.json').success(function(thList) {

                $scope.names = thList;

            });

        };

        $scope.send = function() {

            $http.post('ca/set/3').success(function() {

                $scope.fetchList();

            });

        };

        $scope.fetchList();

}
```

Comment: The error has been disappeared, but there is another problem: the fetchList function doesn't want to work. When I've keep the "new" declaration:

  `$scope.fetchList = new function()`

it works only, when I refresh the browser.

Comment: @ejay you must also add `()` when you call it, like this: `$scope.fetchList();`. I'll update the answer with the correct code.

Comment: My fault, I forgot aboout it. Thanks!

Comment: @ejay no problem. If everything works can you please mark the answer as correct? :)

Answer (score 41):

Just wanted to add for anybody receiving this error, it can also be seen if you, like me, make the n00b mistake of creating a variable with the same name as function (the function being called from ng-click:

```
$scope.addTask = {};

$scope.addTask = function() {};
```

Comment: I got that error, because I wrote `ng-repeat="f in foo()"` instead of `ng-repeat="f in foo"`.

Comment: @6footunder, fantastic, it's nice catch, I wasted 3 hours looking for this problem. **Function Name and relative Variable name should not be same**.

Comment: i got it because i named a function the same as the controller **ControllerAs syntax**

Comment: It also occurred to me because i used the same name in form name and in form submit. So indeed, nice catch!