# Angular v1.2.25 error "fnPtr is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, prototype

I get this error with no particular pattern. The page used to work, but now this error is messing up everything for me. Is there a good way of debugging or tracing down the problem?

```
Error: fnPtr is not a function
Parser.prototype.functionCall/<@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/angular/angular.js:10847:15
OPERATORS["&&"]@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/angular/angular.js:10198:45
Parser.prototype.binaryFn/<@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/angular/angular.js:10600:14
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/angular/angular.js:12532:34
initialize/$scope.loadReasonCodes/<@http://localhost:15987/scripts/voController.js:286:13
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:3062:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:3174:7
done@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:8249:5
.send/callback@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:8792:8
@debugger eval code:1:1
consoleLog/<@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/angular/angular.js:10071:18
$ExceptionHandlerProvider/this.$get</<@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/angular/angular.js:7364:7
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/angular/angular.js:12559:19
getPoLineDetails/<@http://localhost:15987/scripts/voController.js:347:9
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:3062:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:3174:7
done@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:8249:5
.send/callback@http://localhost:15987/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js:8792:8
consoleLog/<()angular.js (line 10071)
$ExceptionHandlerProvider/this.$get</<()angular.js (line 7364)
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest()angular.js (line 12559)
initialize/$scope.loadReasonCodes/<()voController.js (line 286)
jQuery.Callbacks/fire()jquery-1.10.2.js (line 3062)
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith()jquery-1.10.2.js (line 3174)
done()jquery-1.10.2.js (line 8249)
.send/callback()jquery-1.10.2.js (line 8792)
consoleLog/<()angular.js (line 10071)
$ExceptionHandlerProvider/this.$get</<()angular.js (line 7364)
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest()angular.js (line 12559)
getPoLineDetails/<()voController.js (line 347)
jQuery.Callbacks/fire()jquery-1.10.2.js (line 3062)
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith()jquery-1.10.2.js (line 3174)
done()jquery-1.10.2.js (line 8249)
.send/callback()
```

The error *might* be in this section

```
function getPoLineDetails($scope) {
    $.ajax({
        url: api + 'pos',
        data: { po: $scope.vo.PO, lines: $scope.vo.PoLineNumbers.join(','), detailId: $scope.vo.Id },
        success: function (data) {
            $scope.vo.PoLines = data;
            if ($scope.vo.Id != undefined && $scope.vo.Id != null && $scope.vo.Id != -1) {
                $.each($scope.vo.CostBreakdown, function (index, item) {
                    //no content here yet
                });
            }
            $scope.$digest();
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: The best way is to add your code with the error ! It's sounds like you are using `fnPtr` somewhere not like you should but ...

Comment: In that case, it might be indirectlly. I have no reference to `fnPtr` in my code.

Comment: My sentence was not clear probably. `fnPtr` is a "generic" error. Somewhere you are doing something wrong with a function. But without the code, we can't help you.

Comment: ok. So it might not be related to angular?

Comment: It is related to angular. For example here it's a syntax error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208518/angularjs-error-fnptr-is-not-a-function. It can be differents things and we can't take a guess.

Comment: ok. Then I will try to limit my code so that it can be presented here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this kind of error when I use the same name for a variable and a function. Is that your case?

Like this:

```
    $scope.search = 'search';
    $scope.search = function(){}
```

Comment: @Jood I have now gone through my code, and in a HTML view, i had added () by a mistake. So, you were right. Thank you.